# Feed for Sitecore Marketplace Modules

Tags: sitecore-marketplace

I don't know if this should be a UserVoice request - but thought of asking here first.

We know that there are new Modules posted on the Marketplace quite frequently, but we don't know about them, till we go and search for a specific requirement that we have.

We have a feed for Sitecore Blogs written by various Sitecore Enthusiasts, a feed for Sitecore Documentation and Knowledge base articles. These feeds help the whole community to know about the latest article written and when read and aware, its simply going to that blog article for some help when required.

I am sure it would help for new Marketplace Modules as well. But I don't know if we have a feed for new modules posted on Marketplace. 
If not can we have one?

**[UPDATE 11th Oct 2016]** Posted as an idea on UserVoice. 
https://sitecore.uservoice.com/forums/429883-sitecore-mvp/suggestions/16591489-feed-for-sitecore-marketplace-modules

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a question for here but I'll try and help anyway. I don't know of a feed but are you on the Sitecore slack? as if so I'd suggest asking if a channel can be setup there that people can subscribe to for #modules. There is a #blogfeed on Slack already where people share blog post urls so perhaps people can post links here for any new modules (Marketplace or otherwise)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a feature request rather then a question.

Comment: @Anicho: Appreciate your time to vote, but as I mentioned, I don't know if a feed exists, I'd wait for Mark or someone from Sitecore to confirm. If it doesn't, I add it to uservoice.

Comment: @aseabridge: Thanks for that, I am on Slack and on the channel you mentioned as well. I feel a feed is better.

Comment: @VarunShringarpure this isn't the place to ask for official responses for sitecore site requests. What aseabridge has said is the best we can probably do as a community. Unless someone wants to scrape the site and make a feed of it.

Comment: In the mean time you can use this gist to query all of the modules sorted by most popular. https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/3f3730646ac82aa076c2

Comment: There is no official feed in Marketplace. But the solution from @MichaelWest looks very interesting :)